# Switching between database files using Room's createFromAsset() returns empty database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-room-prepackageddatabase

I have a `spinner` that I use to switch between `SQLite` database files. Upon the `spinner` selection listener, I pass the relevant database file name to the Room's Database class.

Before switching between databases by calling Room's `createFromAsset()`, I delete the Room's database file to avoid data caches from the previous database.

My problem is that whenever I switch to another `spinner` value, the database returns nothing. Upon reading the database file from the app's data on my phone, the database file is there, but the table has no entries.

**This is spinner callback:**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (mActivateSpinner) {
            
            String newDatabaseName;
            
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    newDatabaseName = "database1.db";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    newDatabaseName = "database2.db";
                    break;

                default:
                    newDatabaseName = "database1.db";
            }

            mViewModel.deleteDatabase(newDatabaseName, () -> runOnUiThread(() -> {                  
                
                //
                // Reading database here returns empty data
                //
                
            }));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

**ViewModel relevant methods**

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    ....
    
    MyRepository mRepository;
    
    public void deleteDatabase(String newDatabaseName, OnCompletionListener listener) {
        MyRepository.resetInstance();
        MyDataBase.resetInstance();
        
        // delete current Room database file
        deleteDatabaseFile(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), "MyDataBaseFile.db", () -> initRepository(newDatabaseName, listener));
    }


    public void initRepository(String newDatabaseName, OnCompletionListener listener) {
        mRepository = MyRepository.getInstance(getApplication(), newDatabaseName, listener);
    }
    
    
    
    public static void deleteDatabaseFile(Context context, String fileName, OnCompletionListener deleteListener) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            File parent = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases");
            File db = new File(parent, fileName);

            if (db.delete()) {
                deleteListener.onComplete();
                Log.d("TAG", "Database deleted");
            } else 
                Log.d("TAG", "Failed to delete database");
            
        }).start();

    }
    
}
```

**Repository relevant methods**

```
public class MyRepository {

    ...
    
    private MyDataBaseDao mDao;
    private static MyRepository INSTANCE;
        
    public static MyRepository getInstance(Application application, String databaseName, OnCompletionListener listener) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new MyRepository(application, databaseName, listener);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    
    private MyRepository(Application application, String databaseName, OnCompletionListener listener) {
        mDao = MyDataBase.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext(), databaseName, listener).getDao();
    }
    
}
```

**Room database**

```
@Database(entities = {MyTable.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class MyDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDataBaseFile.db";

    private static volatile MyDataBase INSTANCE;

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public abstract MyDataBaseDao getDao();

    public static void resetInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }

    static public MyDataBase getInstance(final Context context, String databaseName, OnCompletionListener listener) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            MyDataBase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .createFromAsset("database/" + databaseName)
                            .build();
                            
                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onComplete();

                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

The `listener.onComplete()` gets called, and the database file is there with the expected size, but the table has no data.

Comment: `mViewModel.deleteDatabase(newDatabaseName` You are deleting the newly choosen database. You should delete te old one. Maybe like `mViewModel.deleteDatabase(oldDatabaseName`

Comment: @blackapps sorry if that confuses; the `newDatabaseName` is the file name that I grab from the assets, but the database itself file name must have a persistent name; I call it `MyDataBaseFile.db`, you may notice it in `MyDatabase` class. I didn't pass it to `deleteDatabase()` for simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room creates 3 files for each database, as in my case I name the database `MyDataBaseFile.db`, then Room creates 3 files and name them:

- MyDataBaseFile.db
- MyDataBaseFile.db-wal
- MyDataBaseFile.db-shm

I was just deleting `MyDataBaseFile.db` and leaving the other two files when I switch the spinner value, and deleting the other two files did really shows the new data in the table

Updated the delete method with

```
public static void deleteDatabase(Context context, String databaseName, OnCompletionListener deleteListener) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        File parent = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases");
        if (deleteFile(parent, databaseName + "-wal")
                && deleteFile(parent, databaseName + "-shm")
                && deleteFile(parent, databaseName)) {
            deleteListener.onComplete();
            Log.d(TAG, "Database deleted");
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to delete database");

    }).start();

}

/*
 * Returns:
 * ****   true: if the file doesn't exist or successfully deleted
 * ****   false: if the file can't be deleted
 * */
private static boolean deleteFile(File parent, String child) {
    File file;

    if (parent != null)
        file = new File(parent, child);
    else
        file = new File(child);

    if (file.exists())
        return file.delete();
    else
        return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76296079/how-to-drop-a-room-database), instead of deleting the three files, there is a neat solution by just closing the database with [close()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.html#close()) method, and then just delete the database file.